# How to publish a word document as HTML to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, moss

I have a Word document with images in it.
I would like to publish the document to Sharepoint as HTML in such a way that the images are preserved.  (Referenced in the HTML)  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: This is kind of like your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966749/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-tfs-work-item-as-an-image-not-as-an-attachment), and the answer is probably not, unless you pull out the images and change them to links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was a product by [AIT](http://www.aitag.com/) called [WordToTFS](http://www.aitag.com/word_to_tfs0.0.html?&L=1).

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if there are other options for this in the meantime? I'm trying something similar right now: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302403/show-word-document-as-web-page-in-sharepoint

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Microsoft how-to article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101637801033.aspx):

"To add these objects so that they appear on the converted Web page, **first upload these objects to a document library** (document library: A folder where a collection of files is stored and the files often use the same template. Each file in a library is associated with user-defined information that is displayed in the content listing for that library.)  and then **insert them as linked objects** (from this location) rather than embedded objects in your document."

Comment: I have the same question and not found a solution yet, see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302403/show-word-document-as-web-page-in-sharepoint. For completeness, here is a link to the above article, the original of which is no longer available: https://web.archive.org/web/20100305210302/http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101637801033.aspx